# Integration of a square of a derivative $\int f''(x)dx$

Tags: integration

I was reading a textbook on PDEs and Waves, and it had a line of integration which did not make any sense to me:

> $$(c^2 - 1)f''f'+(\sin f)f' =0 $$
>   can be integrated to produce the first order equation:
>   $$ \frac{1}{2}(c^2-1)(f')^2 - \cos f = a$$

I tried integration by parts which gave me $$(c^2-1) \left((f')^2 - \int(f'')^2\right) - f' \cos f + \int f'' \cos f$$
and now I'm stuck, and not sure how to proceed. I'm not sure how to integrate $\int (f'')^2$, and how to get rid of the factor in front of the trig function.

Comment: How about you work the other way and differentiate $\frac{1}{2}(c^2-1)(f')^2 - \cos f = a$

Comment: The given form is supposed to evoke the chain rule, not integration by parts.

Comment: hints:$$\begin{align} \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}t} \cos(f(t)) &= -\sin f f' \\
\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}t} (f')^2 & = 2f' f''\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh right! So obvious now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $f'' f'$ is the derivative of $(f')^2/2$, and $(\sin f)f'$ is the derivative of $\cos f$.